# I can't add RestKit Framework in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, restkit

I am starting learning about `RestKit API` in iOS.

I followed [This Tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial) to Install RestKit API.

However i followed exactly all of the steps that he provide, i can't add 
`#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>` into my `AppDelegate.m`

Why i can't import it?

Comment: You might want to consider using [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/). It will make the process so much easier.

Comment: Here is the RestKit install guide: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-as-a-Git-Submodule

Comment: That's the same like above tutorials. still can't add. :(

Comment: "The recommended installation mechanism for RestKit is via CocoaPods..." and [they got a guide](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-via-CocoaPods) after that. What is the exact problem? People cannot help you without having a clear image of what the problem really is...

Comment: Yes i am trying to install CocoaPods , but i don't understand how to install,They are not explaning detail. I can't install with $ [sudo] gem install cocoapods.Could you please explain how to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer.

Enter following text and execute in Terminal.

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

After that , the installation steps are completed.